# Passing variable as column name in a select query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've got a variable set at the top of my PHP:

```
$abc = "paid";
```

Now I need to pass it on to the below query as a column name. I tried the below but it did not work.

```
$sql = "SELECT customerID FROM payments WHERE :myVar = :credit";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':credit'=>"0", ':myVar'=>$abc));
```

How do I pass `$abc` on to the select query as a column name?

Comment: What do see when you  do `echo $sql ;`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks. `SELECT customerID FROM payments WHERE :colName = :credit`. But when I replace $abc with a value it returns the correct values. Please note that I just did a minor edit.

Comment: @Saty That won't work. See [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter).

Comment: In simple words you can not use table or column name as binding

Comment: thanks for providing me such useful imformation

Comment: @Hexaholic that's excellent... Any ideas on VladNeacsu's answer. I just tried and it seem to work??

Comment: It trully is a dupplicate, it's the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

Curly brakets (from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

> Complex (curly) syntax
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }.

Your code should something like: `"SELECT customerID FROM payments WHERE {$abc} = :credit";`

Comment: thanks. Works fine :) But I'm a little confused after reading @Hexaholic  comment. Any ideas?

Comment: @Hexaholic comment means you cannot bind column names like you do in `$stmt->execute(array(':credit'=>"0", ':$abc'=>$abc));`. But this solution will work, as my downvoted one è_é...

Answer (score -2):

you cannot bind colname/table name in prepared queries, you could do like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT customerID FROM payments WHERE $abc=:credit";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':credit'=>"0"));
```

Comment: Please, at least, leave a comment when you downvote... I don't understand !